# In php-fpm with nginx, can I disable upload_max_filesize?

Tags: php, security, nginx, upload

I have a nginx server with a php-fpm backend.

On the nginx server, I have a `client_max_body_size` limiting the upload of anything.

So I decide to disable `post_max_size` and `upload_max_size`? They are already limited by the nginx server anyway... And this would avoid duplicate limitation and configuration.

To do that, I did try to set them

```
post_max_size = 0
upload_max_filesize = 0
```

which seem to do the job, while partially documented.

Is this setup safe?

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/questions/611239/increase-php-fpms-max-upload-post-size and the size should be 0 each not -1. But you should not allow unlimited upload to prevent the server from dying and security reasons. Choose a reliable size, you can increase any time.

Comment: @MarkusZeller They're not allowing unlimited upload. They're limiting it in the NGINX configuration, so the PHP configuration is redundant.

Comment: @Barmar I would say this is partially correct. When the nginx size for example is 1 GB and PHP config is 512MB, it is limited to the PHP config size. But the other way around, if PHP is unlimited it is maxed out to 1 GB of the nginx config.

Comment: @MarkusZeller Right. But since they only want to use NGINX configuration, duplicating it in PHP is redundant.

Comment: @Barmar Only if the limits on nginx are higher than in PHP. :)

Comment: @MarkusZeller Of course. But the whole point of what the OP is trying to do is put the limit in just one place.

Comment: @Barmar And he asked `Is this setup safe?`.

Comment: @MarkusZeller It's as safe as putting the same limit in both places.

Comment: Safe for function, but IMHO see it somewhat unsafe for production server setting it to unlimited.

Comment: Sure. If you grant unlimited upload and your server got flooded it will be out of service before can say "reboot". Did you ever experience a server out of disk space? This is just my 50ct.

Comment: Read my very first comment. I just said, unlimited upload is not safe. If it is limited, by whatever, it is better, and that -1 is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This response is not (yet) factual.

Since the NGINX limit the upload size, the limit is de facto applied to any communication to the PHP. The limit in the PHP is thus not necessary.

But this point is based on the fact that NGINX is doing the job correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of [`post_max_size`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) says in the Changelog:

> 5.3.2 , 5.2.12    Allow unlimited post size by setting post_max_size to 0.

so the correct value is `0`, not `-1`. The changelog for 5.3.4 says that this doesn't work when the content type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. But since you have to use `multipart/form-data` to upload files, this isn't relevant when you want to allow large file uploads.

The documentation of `upload_max_size` doesn't say how to make it unlimited, but it seems likely that it would be the same. It should be simple to verify this expectation, and you could submit a bug report to fix the documentation.